# What's the most common word refer to the after death letter?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, meaning-in-context

I am confused between : Will, legacy, Commandment, Precept, Behest, Testament and more.

Which word refer to the declaration or the message by which a person ask the world to do certain things after his death, like his recommendations and the distribution of his property..etc.

Comment: 'Recommendations' and 'distribution of property' are different, which is which different words are used. I think you mean *Will*, for which (in this sense) *testament* is an obsolete synonym. If you can edit the question to be more precise, it can be answered properly.

Comment: Why obsolete? I hear "My [will and testament](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will_and_testament)" often, not just in Shelock Holmes or such

Comment: @mplungjan it's arguably obsolete on its own, much as *wrack* in the sense of ruin is obsolete but still found in the tautologous *wrack and ruin*.

Comment: You might be confusing *behest* with *bequest*.

Comment: @tchrist they might not. The will can be called a *behest*, as it *behests* that the *bequest* be given.

Comment: @JonHanna That’s why I said ***might***. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, Let's say a father wrote a letter to his sons to be opened after his death, Asking them to take care of their disabled sister, and to distribute his money in a certain way.. what should we call that letter?

Comment: @JonHanna I have never heard of wrack - I hear will and testament all the time in any program featuring such documents. Latest in the "BBC Heir hunters"

Comment: @mplungjan I heard "wrack" all the time as a child, particularly if I'd left the living-room in a bit of a mess ;)
How often have you heard "testament" in this sense, outside of the legal doublet?

Comment: you leave me wracked with doubt... However my British spell checked wants that to be wrecked...

Comment: @mplungjan: I guess that proves we Brits aren't exactly world leaders in context-sensitive spell checkers. Either side of the pond, **racked** is far more common than either *wrecked* or *wracked*. As attested by the chart in [an answer to this ELU question](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/38631/2637)

Comment: @Jon: I believe *behest* the noun (itself fairly archaic) comes from the OE verb *haest*, which also gives us *behoves*. I have encountered a good deal of archaism, but never encountered *behest* as a verb.

Comment: @TimLymington I believe you are correct.

Comment: The example was just to show that the word I am looking for is not necessarily means the distribution of his property and money at death. Another example.. Say, a father asking to be buried in the village cemetery. Can we call that a Will?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common is almost certainly *will*. The others are all certainly used, and the doubled-up "will and testament" is quite common particularly in the wording of wills themselves (such doubling up is particularly common in matters of law, as per "aid and abet", "cease and desist", "null and void" an so on). While commonly used in the document itself, and formal legal documents relating to one, it's nowhere near as common as plain *will* in other contexts, including when talking with lawyers.

Of those you list, *legacy* is incorrect, as it refers to the goods and funds bequeathed. As tchrist suggests in the comments it's possible that you meant *bequest* when you said *behest* in which case it would have been an interesting reverse mistake; *bequest* is also what is given (and the verb to describe doing so) while *behest* is the command that it be done and so could be used as another name for a will, albeit a rare one.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes I've heard terms ***last requests, final requests***, or ***final wishes*** used. These aren't necessarily legally binding, like a will, but they are a way to let wishes be passed along to family members.

Sometimes you'll hear about someone getting their "affairs" in order. In this context, "affairs" would cover a will, along with final wishes, and perhaps even arrangement for a particular a burial plot, an epitaph for a tombstone, indications of whether or not the deceased would prefer to be cremated, etc.

A number of funeral homes use terms like "final requests" or "final wishes" in their websites, as do other funeral planning guides, such as [this one](http://thefuneralsource.org/plan04.html).

Comment: Now i can understand clearly, that the Will is dedicated for legal wishes only. Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

I would call it *The father’s will (and testament)* - the latter part seems not used much anymore

**Testament** - from [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/testament)

> 1. a person’s will, especially the part relating to personal property:
>      father’s will and testament
> 2. something that serves as a sign or evidence of a specified fact, event, or quality:
>      growing attendance figures are a testament to the event’s popularity
> 3. (in biblical use) a covenant or dispensation.
>      (Testament) a division of the Bible. See also Old Testament, New Testament.
>      (Testament) a copy of the New Testament:
>      he was able to buy a Testament
>
> **Origin:**
>
> Middle English: from Latin testamentum 'a will' (from testari 'testify'), in Christian Latin also translating Greek diathēkē 'covenant'

**Testament** [free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/testament)

> **3.** Law A written document providing for the disposition of a person's property after death; a will.

**Will** from [free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/will)

> **7.**
>   a. A legal declaration of how a person wishes his or her possessions to be disposed of after death.
>   b. A legally executed document containing this declaration.

Answer (score 0):

@Ala You ask, in your subsequent comment: 'Let's say a father wrote a letter to his sons to be opened after his death, Asking them to take care of their disabled sister'.

There are a host of questions which arise. Is the disabled sister 'legally competent'. e.g. Is she mentally or physically disabled? If the former the usual thing would be for the father to leave money in trust for her and to appoint the sons as trustees.

I am not sure what happens if someone refuses to act as a trustee. Perhaps the court of probate can appoint a replacement. Normally before writing a will in this way one asks the proposed trustees if they would be willing to act.

No one has the power to require another person by way of a will to do something e.g.'look after your sister'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, That example was just to show that the word  I am looking for is not necessarily means the distribution of his property and money at death. Another example.. Say, a father asking to be buried in the village cemetery. Is that a Will?

Comment: @Ala As I am not a qualified solicitor, if you need specific advice on the making of a will I think you need to consult an appropriate legal professional in your own country. However I do understand that in the UK there can only be one will (including codicils thereto) at the time of a person's death. And it is not unusual to include the person's wishes as to burial/cremation arrangements.

Comment: The technical term for such things as burial requests and "look after your sister" is a Letter of Wishes, and it has no legal force, though obviously considerable moral force. I don't believe this is used by anyone but lawyers; 'The Will' is probably what most people would say, particularly since such a Letter is often attached to the actual will.