# Nerve-racking or nerve-wrecking or nerve-wracking

Tags: phrases, expressions

I have seen all three forms of the term used interchangeably and am confused. Which one is correct? Is it dependent on the context?
Is it okay to say, for instance,

> "The wait is nerve-wracking"

Comment: Very closely related: [Which is correct: “rack my brain” or “wrack my brain”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38630/which-is-correct-rack-my-brain-or-wrack-my-brain)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - you are actually suggesting it is a duplicate. I judiciously think it is not.

Comment: @Josh no, if i thought it was an exact duplicate I would have voted to close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct spelling is : ***[nerve-racking](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nerve-wracking)*** or ***nerve-wracking:***

> - extremely irritating, annoying, or trying:
>     *a nerve-racking day; a nerve-racking noise.*

(Dictionary.com)

***Nerve-wrecking*** is a less common variant, probably from a spelling mistake. See [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nerve%20racking%2Cnerve%20wracking%2Cnerve%20wrecking&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnerve%20racking%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnerve%20wracking%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnerve%20wrecking%3B%2Cc0)

From [The Vocabularist: Nerve-racking or nerve-wracking?](http://www.bbc.com/news/blogs-magazine-monitor-34626663):

> - ***The first recorded use of nerve-racking is in a letter by the poet Shelley in 1812, telling his friend he is glad to be away from the "nerve-racking and spirit-quelling metropolis".***
> - But "rack" - from a family of English words to do with stretching - had long been used in connection with torture, and often applied to parts of the body.
>     In Milton's Paradise Lost (1667) humanity's coming afflictions include *"Joint-racking Rheums" while the expression "Racking your brains" goes back at least as far as 1680.*
> - ***In the early 20th Century "nerve-wracking" also began to appear - in the Times it was in an advert in 1905, and a 1910 news report on Peary's planned polar expedition. The New York Times wrote "the air of America is invigorating and nerve-wracking" in 1908.***
> - *"Wrack" comes from another set of Germanic words with meanings shading from revenge into punishment and destruction, including "wreak" and "wreck".*
> - ***Some people prefer "nerve-wracking" because they associate it with wrecking - the wording "nervous wreck" is recorded as early as 1871.***
> - ***It was always likely that rack and wrack should overlap.***  Wr- at the start of a word has been hard to pronounce from the time when w began to sound in Old English as it does today.

(www.bbc.com)

Comment: +1 from me because users who downvote solid answers are a bane on EL&U.