# Is there an idiom/phrase which contains the word "head" to mean "thinking hard to solve a problem"?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I am looking for an idiom or phrase that means "thinking hard by myself to solve a problem". I hope the idiom or phrase has the word "head" in it.

Example: I have been ____ head ______ for the last 5 days to solve this math puzzle.

Comment: You've been *head down* for the last 5 days, working on your problem. (You haven't even had time to look up at the rest of the world.)

Comment: "have one's head screwed on right : to have good judgment"

Comment: This is what we call a "guessing game" question. They're not a good fit for the site. ([more](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/))

Comment: In case your answer doesn't really need the word "head" in it (I assume this is a homework assignment), you could also use "brainstorming". I think "head down" is the right answer for the homework though. :)

Comment: My first thought to fill in the first gap with "giving". Then i realized... :D

Comment: "Head down" sounds odd to me. I'd say "heads down" (despite, admittedly, only having the one).

Comment: "*In your own **head**space*" means something like *obsessing over* or, more positively, *meditating*. It's a fairly recent, niche-type phrase, though, not a widespread idiom.

Answer (score 66):

I have been **scratching my head** for the last 5 days to solve this math puzzle.

The Cambridge Dictionary says the following with regard to British English:

> **scratch your head**
>
> - to think hard about something
> - A lot of people must be scratching
>     their heads about which way to vote.

It also says the following with regard to American English:

> **scratch your head**
>
> - to have difficulty understanding something
> - All I can do is scratch my
>     head and ask why.

([link](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/scratch-your-head))

To address the point that you want something that means "thinking hard" instead of "to have difficulty understanding," I can attest as a native speaker of English in the United States that to scratch one's head does imply effort being put into solving a problem. Also, if someone is spending 5 days on a math puzzle they must find it difficult, the implication is present that some effort is being put into solving it is there anyway.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Someone please find the courage to improve this answer because the suggestion's a good one ;)

Comment: Interesting, I'm from the US as well and when I say "I'm scratching my head" it means someone did something stupid and I don't get it, but also don't care. As in "the way you're standing in the rain has me scratching my head".

Comment: As a US speaker, "scratching my head" does not imply thinking hard to me. I'd understand it, but I'd think it's an odd usage of that expression. To me "banging my head against the wall" would be more reflective of thinking hard to solve a difficult problem.

Comment: @PierreArlaud - When this happens, go ahead and jump into the editor's seat.  This shouldn't require courage -- just a general attitude of civic-mindedness.

Comment: @Carl You scratch your head because you're thinking about the stupidity.

Comment: I think this is as close as it gets within the given constraints, although I agree with Carl and Daniel that "scratching my head" strongly suggests *confusion* rather than being *deep in thought*. [racking one's brains](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38630/which-is-correct-rack-my-brain-or-wrack-my-brain) has the desired meaning.

Answer (score 50):

You have been **trying to wrap your head around** it.

[The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/wrap+your+head+around) says:

> wrap (one's) head around
>
> To comprehend something that one considers
> challenging, confusing, or a foreign concept.

So your sentence could be modified a bit:

I have been trying to wrap my head around this math puzzle for the last 5 days.

EDIT:
As per [Mari-Lou A](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/44619/mari-lou-a)'s comment, in British English you can also say that you **can't get your head around it**.

From the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/can-t-get-your-head-around-sth):

> If you say that you can't get your head around something, you mean
> that you cannot understand it:
>
> *I just can't get my head around these tax forms.*

So the sentence would be:

I haven't been able to get my head around this math puzzle for the last 5 days.

Comment: I like this one the best

Comment: very similar idea, apparently British English, but I'd say any Anglophone speaker would understand it, [can't get your head around sth](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/can-t-get-your-head-around-sth)  If you want, you can also add this suggestion.

Comment: I'd say this phrase is entirely about *understanding*, as opposed to solving.

Comment: @Rycochet - the question was about *thinking hard*, so I think this phrase is appropriate here

Comment: Wrapping your head around something means you got it. Doesn't mean you are _trying_ to get it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - that's why I wrote *I have been trying to wrap my head around it*

Comment: I think this is the closest, but none of the answers hit the second part of the OP - "...to solve a problem" (and I can't think of any off the top of my head)

Comment: I suggest bolding the "trying to" part as it is part of the suggested phrase :)

Comment: @Rycochet: That element of context is provided by the OP in the trailing part of their example sentence.

Answer (score 45):

You've ***been banging your head against a wall***.

[The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bang+my+head+against+a+wall)  gives an example that is almost the same as your sample sentence.

> To attempt continuously and fruitlessly to accomplish some task or achieve some goal that is or seems ultimately hopeless.
>
> - *I feel like I've been **banging my head against a wall** trying to understand this math equation.*
> - *Some people are never going to agree with you on this, so it's no use banging your head against a wall trying to convince everyone.*

Of course if you actually solved the problem, and did it in a clever way, someone might tell you that you *really **used your head** (there)*.

Comment: I would say that "banging one's head" implies a fruitless and stressful experience.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins That could be exactly what OP is looking for.

Comment: I have heard people use "banging my head against <X>" where X may be something like "that bug" or specifically "bug 1234". I have seen it used such that the implication would be that sooner or later, either the bug or the speaker's head is going to break.

Answer (score 18):

There's **racking my brain**, which means exactly that and sort of comes close to an expression with "head" in it.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/rack-your-brains

Comment: In my experience "racking my brain" is only used when trying to *remember* something, not in trying to *understand* something.

Comment: @AndyT, I don't know; I'm getting to the point where I rack my brains to figure out how to tie my shoes.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

> I've been **doing my head in** trying to come up with an answer.

Or less clumsily,

> This maths question **has been doing my head in** for the last five days.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/do-sb-s-head-in

Comment: Isn't this just a more recent version of "banging my head against a wall", or is the etymology different somehow?

Answer (score 4):

If you're working with someone else, you can **put your heads together** to find a solution.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/put-their-heads-together

Answer (score 3):

You can "**use your head**" to solve a problem. Generally that implies thinking harder (or smarter) than you generally might do, in order to come to the correct answer/conclusion by yourself.

Comment: Often found in the form "Now that's using your head!" to praise someone for good thinking.

Answer (score 1):

The term "headwork" comes to mind:

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/headwork

It would need to need some (head)work to fit in your sentence, however. Perhaps "doing some serious headwork." The verb form "headworking" doesn't appear in MW, or other sources I've found.

Answer (score 1):

To **break** or **bust your head** on a problem means to think really hard about it. I can't find it in online dictionaries but Google comes up with many examples.

David Bowie's *Moonage Daydream* has the variant *I'm busting up my brains for the words*.

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking about that problem "**makes my head explode**".

This has the connotation of extreme frustration while trying to understand or solve a problem. It is the logical consequence of "banging my head against the wall".

Answer (score 0):

Jerome Rodale, [*The Synonym Finder*](https://books.google.com/books?id=O1v2CwAAQBAJ&pg=PT746&dq=%22trouble+one%27s+head%22+Rodale&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYkIDZgY_eAhVkJTQIHXXwCIkQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22trouble%20one's%20head%22%20Rodale&f=false) (1978) suggests **trouble one's head**.

Christine Ammer, *The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms*, second edition (2013) offers this entry for the phrase:

> **trouble one's head with** Also **trouble oneself about**. Bother or worry about, as in *Don't trouble your head with these details; I'll take care of it*, or *It seems to me that teachers should trouble themselves more about teaching and less about manners*. The first term dates from the mid-1600s, the variant from the early 1500s.