# Is there any word, alternative to the idiom, "rack one's brain"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, idioms

What word can I use in place of the idiom "rack one's brain," which means **to strain in mental effort, esp to remember something** (from [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/rack-ones-brains))?

For instance, a teacher put a chalk box in the principal's office yesterday, but today he is trying his level best to remember where he put that box.

Can I use the verb [remind](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/remind) along with a reflexive pronoun, as in: "he reminded himself... ."

> - A teacher [verb] for where he put that box.

---

The post ([here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/374510/is-there-an-idiom-phrase-which-contains-the-word-head-to-mean-thinking-hard-t)), which was proposed as duplicate to this question, is irrelevent here. I am just asking about a verb which denotes thinking very hard to remember anything, **not the verb that denotes solving problems, like in Maths**.

> **Have a look at this image.**
>
> [image: picture of a boy racking up his brain]

Comment: The phrase *trying very hard* conveys the "strain in mental effort" part, so this would work: "The teacher was trying very hard to remember where he put the box." (No special word needed in place of *remember*.)

Comment: @Lawrence, I have edited the example sentence as well, if you are **still** not satisfied with that, can you please edit it further?

Comment: I've edited to help improve the phrasing of the question, but I've left the sample sentence alone because *its* phrasing is central to your question.

Comment: You're welcome :) . If it wasn't a physical object, you could use *strained/reached/stretched*. With a physical object, the physical interpretation dominates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an idiom/phrase which contains the word "head" to mean "thinking hard to solve a problem"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/374510/is-there-an-idiom-phrase-which-contains-the-word-head-to-mean-thinking-hard-t)

Comment: Does it have to drop into the sample sentence ("A teacher ___ for where he put that box.") exactly? If so, none of the current answers work.

Comment: Rodale's [_Synonym Finder_](https://books.google.com/books?id=kjWZMyVa6jgC&pg=PA270&dq=%22cudgel+one%27s+brain%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGr5mF_47eAhUkO30KHRElCLYQ6AEIYzAJ#v=onepage&q=%22cudgel%20one's%20brain%22&f=false) (1978) suggests such phrases as "cudgel one's brain, "trouble one's head," "dwell on," and "put one's mind to." A [thesaurus from 1859](https://books.google.com/books?id=rKpDAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA455&dq=%22cudgel+one%27s+brain%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGr5mF_47eAhUkO30KHRElCLYQ6AEITzAG#v=onepage&q=%22cudgel%20one's%20brain%22&f=false) suggests "strain or crack one's invention."

Answer (score 7):

There're several good choices.

**Agonize**, as [Spencer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/468146/is-there-any-word-alternative-to-the-idiom-rack-ones-brain/468184#comment1130357_468151) mentioned, could be useful.

> Ahmed *agonized* over where he placed the chalk box.

**[Mull](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/mull)** is another one.

> Ahmed was *mulling* over where he placed the chalk box.

**[Ruminate](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/ruminate)** is a third.

> Ahmed was lost in his *ruminations* over where he placed the chalk box.

You could also do something like **[struggle](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/struggle)**.

> Ahmed *struggled* to remember the location of the chalk box.

Comment: Good first answer. To make it even better add the definitions you link as citation in the answer, that way if the links ever go dead, the information is still preserved.

Comment: The verb **agonize** has something to do with taking decisions, not remembering something. Similarly, **mull** also suggests the same, as **agonize** does.

Comment: Actually, agonize could refer to either making a decision or attempting to remember. Your idiom is literally listed as a synonym.

ag·o·nize
verb

past tense: agonized; past participle: agonized
undergo great mental anguish through worrying about something.

synonyms: worry, fret, fuss, brood, overthink, upset oneself, rack one's brains, wrestle with oneself, be worried, be anxious, feel uneasy, exercise oneself; informal: stew

p.s. Your edit, while technically correct, is a bit pedantic. :)

Comment: a) I agree that **rack one's brain** is synonymous to **agonize**, but both doesn't have the exact meaning. b) it's good to be pedantic sometimes :)

Answer (score 4):

**agony**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/agony)

> 1. To suffer mental anguish or 
>      worry about something

Your proposed sentence using 'remind' would not be correct:

> A teacher was trying very hard to remind himself of that box.

Consider"

> The teacher was in **agony** trying to remember where he had put X.

I you desire to use remember/remind, consider:

> A teacher was trying very hard to remember where he put X.

Comment: You need a verb, so perhaps"agonize" would be better than "agony".

Answer (score 1):

Try **[recollect](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/recollect)**:

> remember (something); call to mind. (Oxford)
>
> - The teacher **recollected** where he put that box.

Answer (score 1):

What about [**ponder**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ponder)?

> To reflect or consider with thoroughness and care.

You could say, "All day long, the teacher pondered over the location of the misplaced chalk."

Answer (score 1):

Fret or mull [over] connote more anxiety than ponder or deliberate.  Cogitate is in between.  You could also say you’re working or stuck on a math problem (or wherever else it’s plain from context that your effort is mental).